# Azure function is running out of memory

Tags: .net, docker, azure-functions, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-blob-storage

I've an Azure function V3 with queue trigger written in .net core 3.1. My function is containerized and goes straight to ACR. Inside of the function I am doing some heavy work (uploading/downloading file from Azure blob and doing some computations). Now the issue is, in case of huge computations my function sometimes run out of memory and thus the other messages in queue have to wait for a long time.

1. Now what I want is to either parallelize the processing of long running computations (I can calculate in the beginning if the process will take time). And once the processing is done from all processes, I want to get results from all processes. Also considering errors in any of the process.
2. Somehow starting a new process to do the computations within the docker container (Not sure if it's possible or not)

Any suggestions? or is there anyway I save the function from running out of memory?

PS: Function timeout is already set to 1hour.

Comment: 2 is as easy as to post a message to a queue, or forward the incoming message to a queue, and pick it uo in a seperate containerized process. Other question: these computations, is that mainy cpu bound work or I/O?

Comment: They are actually CPU bound tasks. Can you give me any hint how to achieve 2nd point?